# Disabling ListItem selectability

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

As you can see from the screenshot below I have a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) with multiple items in it. No matter what I try I can't seem to make the list item's not be selectable. I've tried all of the follow (in the XML layout for the ListView), but the items are STILL selectable with both a finger and the scroll wheel.

```
android:clickable="false" 
android:longClickable="false" 
android:focusable="false" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Any suggestions?

[image: activity]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each row of a`ListView` are selectable, you might be interested in [**`TableLayout`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html), where items are not selectable, to achieve what you are looking for.

#### EDIT:

After searching a bit more, I found [this archive post](http://osdir.com/ml/AndroidDevelopers/2009-02/msg00767.html) which suggests you try:

```
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
   return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
  return false;
}
```

Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: That did it... thanks. This should really be settable in the XML.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you on that, maybe in the future they will produce better documentations online and have more attributes set via the XML.